# What is a word for the 7 deadly sins AND the 7 heavenly virtues all together?

Tags: single-word-requests

Obviously, just for the 7 deadly sins you would use 'sin' and for the 7 heavenly virtues you would use 'virtue' or 'heavenly' but what word would you use to describe all 14 of them together?

Comment: I reckon that wouldn't be necessary, because everyone knows them. It's common sense.

Comment: Christianity is the major religion in both major English-speaking countries UK and USA, so yes it's common sense.

Comment: Is "seven deadly sins and their virtue counterparts" good enough?

Comment: "The fourteen equipoised vicetues"?

Comment: Trouble in paradise.

Comment: The 14 heavenly sins? Sounds perhaps a bit too much like a fortnight of amusing debauchery …

Comment: We need more context, why would you need such a thing?  How specific is it to the Catholic dogma and how specific to the notion of morality as a whole, vs, as has been floated, personality.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *dogma*: an official system of principles or tenets concerning faith, morals, behavior, etc., as of a church.

Also consider using *tenets* as a descriptor, e.g. "the 14 religious tenets of good and evil."

Comment: If you are citing a published source, please tell us which one.

Answer (score -2):

That's actually a great question.  I believe there's no ready-to-use term, no.

If I was writing about them, I'd maybe refer to the 14 "heavenly qualities" - I don't think you could do a lot better than that.

(So for example, ".. and of the 14 qualities, only 5 refer to sexuality .." etc.)

You could possibly use "dictums". You could also possibly just use **"acts"** or "actions", which is what they are.  Hope it helps.

Again there is in fact no word that we "all already use" for that super-set.  (I'm fairly certain.)

(By the way, if you very simply look in a dictionary, you'll see that sins are "acts" .. virtues are more "behaviours".  Since, indeed, they are two different categories of things, I feel you could edge it and call them the 14 heavenly 'qualities' if you were writing about them.  But I think the key is there is NO word existing now for these 14 .. heavenly sin-virtue specifications.)

Note that you could possibly call the, uh, edicts themselves .. edicts.

But you want a word for the "thing" referred to in the edict .. right?

Comment: These are neither dictums nor actions. They are concepts, not sayings, and indeed patience and restraint could be interpreted as the very opposite of action.

Comment: For sure, as I said, para 6, the sins tend to be **actions** but the virtues are more "qualities" - broader sustained "behavioural patterns."

Comment: Then why do you suggest *acts* or *actions* for the entire collection?

Comment: As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins) says, they're all ***personality traits***. You can line up ***pride, avarice, envy, wrath, lust, gluttony, sloth*** with their respective "opposites" as ***humility, charity, kindness, patience, chastity, temperance, diligence***. So arguably we could just call them [***clines***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cline), where if your *actual* behaviour is close to either of the extremes, you must be either a saint or a sinner.

Comment: nice point on "traits" or "personality traits" - but on the other hand, I dunno, like "murder" is it a "trait"?  You can totally see what the OPs asking though, is there simply a superset word for sin/virtue?  Again I'm troubled by the fact that a sin is an act; a virtue is a 'quality'.  And there's so many different ways these things are presented in the bible, catechisms or whatever.

Comment: @JoeBlow - Murder might not be a personality trait, but it isn't one of the 7 deadly sins either.

Comment: oldster - good point!  :)